# Why moderncv documentation is not shown?

Tags: moderncv, documentation

`moderncv` package is installed in my distribution. But when I try to open documentation using `texdoc moderncv` some text are appeared instead of documentation. Why?

Comment: The author of the template simply didn't bother to write a documentation. You either need some LaTeX skills or pure luck to make changes.

Comment: What's the best way to obtain the former @Johannes_B ?

Comment: @user129393192 read an introduction to LaTeX.

Comment: You mean this https://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`texdoc` shows you the documentation PDF, or, if not available, the README file. [`moderncv`](//ctan.org/pkg/moderncv) has no documentation on CTAN, but a README and that's shown.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the `Example`subdirectory`which has some commented`templates`and the resulting`.pdf`s.